# Symfony2: how to exclude 1 js asset file?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

By default, all my scripts are loaded into the `head` section, and inside the folder `js/`. but, I want one of the script files not to be loaded with the others. How to exclude this file?

Code base.html.twig

```
....
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts 
        '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.11.0.js'
        '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/js/*'
        '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/js/*/*'%}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
....
```

code index.html.twig

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}
....
{# in footer #}
<script src="{{ asset('/bundles/acmedemo/js/clipboard.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/bundles/acmedemo/js/ZeroClipboard.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/bundles/acmedemo/js/config.js') }}"></script>
...
```

output

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app_dev.php/js/e900114_jquery-1.11.0_1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app_dev.php/js/e900114_part_2_ZeroClipboard.min_1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app_dev.php/js/e900114_part_2_ZeroClipboard_2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app_dev.php/js/e900114_part_2_bootstrap.min_3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app_dev.php/js/e900114_part_2_clipboard_4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app_dev.php/js/e900114_part_2_config_5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app_dev.php/js/e900114_part_2_daterangepicker_6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app_dev.php/js/e900114_part_2_moment_8.js"></script>
....
{# in footer #}
<script src="/bundles/acmedemo/js/clipboard.js"></script>
<script src="/bundles/acmedemo/js/ZeroClipboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bundles/acmedemo/js/config.js"></script>
```

ZeroClipboard repeated

Comment: please, add the code you use to load the js folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an internal folder. put all files in it except the one you want to include.

In your head load the internal folder. and to include all files load the external folder.